# dockerized logstash is generating huge log files

Tags: docker, logstash, aws-ecs

I'm running a logstash container in AWS ECS from the following image

```
docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:5.5.3
```

Everything is at default and I am not using the stdout plugin. But logstash still outputs all the log items to stdout and the container is generating a huge log file at

```
/var/lib/docker/containers/51889a642e7e1252b5825379b11cea4e064cda519e8a6a4194335d9e8eb11616/51889a642e7e1252b5825379b11cea4e064cda519e8a6a4194335d9e8eb11616-json.log
```

Is there any way to disable this from `logstash` side? AWS ECS does not seem to support `--log-driver none` just yet.

`logstash.conf` and `logstash.yml` are as follow:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxxxx logstash]$ cat logstash.conf 
input {
  sqs {
    queue => "compute-logs"
    polling_frequency => 5
    region => "ap-southeast-1"
    type => "compute-logs"
  }
}
...
output {
  elasticsearch {
    codec => "json"
    hosts => "https://xxxxx.ap-southeast-1.es.amazonaws.com:443"
    user => "logstash"
    index => "%{name}"
    template => "/usr/share/logstash/config/elasticsearch_template.json"
    template_name => "logstash"
    template_overwrite => true
  }
}
[ec2-user@ip-xxxxx logstash]$ ls
elasticsearch_template.json  logstash.conf  logstash.yml
[ec2-user@ip-xxxxx logstash]$ cat logstash.yml 
http.host: "0.0.0.0"
path.config: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.url: http://elasticsearch:9200
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.username: logstash_system
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.password: changeme
xpack.monitoring.enabled: false
log.level: error
```

Comment: Please share your logstash config file.

Comment: Added @whites11

Comment: And still you see your events in the log? That's weird. Are you sure logstash is actually using your config file?

Comment: @whites11 you are right turns out I mounted the `logstash.conf` file as `logstash.json` and it didn't overwrite the default `logstash.conf` file. so the default stdout logging was still enabled. fixed that and all good now.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution for
docker swarm service:

```
services:
  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:6.4.2
    ports:
      - 25000:25000
      - 25000:25000/udp
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "10"
```